# user feed, a relic of a discontinued service

Tags: feature-request, feeds, user-communication

I found a user I believe to be a terrific resource. Naturally, I wanted to follow him on his answers, questions and contributions. After thumbing around his profile, I discovered the hard way that this service was discontinued by being directed [here](http://www.google.com/reader/about/#stream/feed/https://askubuntu.com/feeds/user/3940)

Is there a way we can provide a new user feed service?

Answer (score 6):

The user feed itself still exists, the feed reader you were using (Google Reader) was discontinued, however.

Get a new Atom feed reader and subscribe to this feed: https://askubuntu.com/feeds/user/3940

You should be able to find a few replacements on Google: [google reader replacement - Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=google+reader+replacement)

Reference:

- http://googleblog.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html